# tbl_regression, mfx, and p values

Tags: tidyverse

This simple example throws an error for tbl_regression with mfx, but tbl_merge still works.

```
library("gtsummary")
library("mfx")
data(sleep)

m1 <- tbl_regression(glm(data=sleep, group~extra, family = "binomial"))
m2 <- tbl_regression(logitmfx(data=sleep, group~extra, atmean = TRUE))
tbl_merge(list(m1,m2), tab_spanner=c("",""))
```

However, tbl_merge breaks if I label the variables

```
library("labelled")
var_label(sleep$extra) <- "Hrs of sleep"
m1 <- tbl_regression(glm(data=sleep, group~extra, family = "binomial"))
m2 <- tbl_regression(logitmfx(data=sleep, group~extra, atmean = TRUE))
tbl_merge(list(m1,m2), tab_spanner=c("",""))
```

How do I add the marginal effects into a single table with labelled vars?

AND, how do I drop the CI's and change the p-values to asterisks?